# Magento : Admin User Save After Event not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, event-observer, customer

I am using this code

```
     <adminhtml>
         <admin_user_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <my_test_admin_user_save_after_observer>
                        <class>MY_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>userSaveAfter</method>
                    </my_test_admin_user_save_after_observer>
                </observers>
         </admin_user_save_after>  
    </adminhtml>
```

This not call observer `MY_Test_Model_Observer`

Any idea how to call admin user save after event.

Comment: By admin user, do you mean System > Permission > Users or System > My Account user?

Comment: Can you tell me how to get email of user with this event in magento 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `admin_user_save_after` event as there is no event with the specified name in magento.
If you want to run your observer function after you save a Role user, Created from System > Permissions > User, you can use below code,

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_permissions_user_save>
            <observers>
                <my_test_admin_user_save_after_observer>
                    <class>MY_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>userSaveAfter</method>
                </my_test_admin_user_save_after_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_permissions_user_save>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

If you want to run observer function after you save main admin user from System > My Account, you can use below code,

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_account_save>
            <observers>
                <my_main_admin_user_save_after_observer>
                    <class>MY_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>userSaveAfter</method>
                </my_main_admin_user_save_after_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_account_save>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```